# How can I transfer files to hosts use ansible?

Tags: ansible

How can I transfer files to hosts use ansible?

I installed ansible in my ansible-node,
and in the /etc/ansible/hosts, there are so many hosts:

```
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
10.10.10.4
....
10.10.10.200
```

I checked the ping, all alive:

```
# ansible all -m ping -k
```

but I want to upload a directory to each host from my ansible-node.
how to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: myHostGroupInHostsFile
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Copy /etc/directory
    copy:
      src: /Path/on/ansible_node/directory/
      dest: /etc/directory
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0644'
```

And start the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook myPlaybook.yml
```

Comment: With the `/` at the end of the `src` path, only the contents of the directory will be copied. If you want to copy the whole directory incl. contents, leave out the `/`. [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-src)